# Video created in OpenCv does open, but shows nothing

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I've been trying to merge some pictures to create a video, all of this using Opencv. But, the problem here is that Opencv does create the .avi file and it opens, using VLC Media Player, but when I'm trying to watch the video created, it shows nothing and doesn't show how long does the video last. However, the file size is around 6kb. There are 18 images and they have an average size os 252kb. I think that's too weird and incoherent.

Here's a look at my code:

```
import cv2
import os
frameSize = (500, 500)
with os.scandir('Taylor') as Taylor_Images:
  for image in Taylor_Images:
      print(image.name)
with os.scandir('Taylor_5') as Taylor5_Images:
  for image in Taylor5_Images:
      print(image.name)
```

```
image_Taylor = []
image_Taylor_5 = []
ext_2 = '.png'
adding = '_5'
path_2 = 'Taylor_5/'
ext = '.png'
path = 'Taylor/'
for i in range(1,10):
   img_name = str(i) + ext
   img = path + str(i) + ext
   image_Taylor.append(img)
   img_name_2 = str(i) + ext_2
   img_2 = path_2 + str(i) + adding + ext_2
   image_Taylor_5.append(img_2)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video2.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 60, frameSize)
for i in range(0,9):
   img = cv2.imread(image_Taylor[i])
   out.write(img)
   img_2 = cv2.imread(image_Taylor_5[i])
   out.write(img_2)
out.release()
```

**Update 1**

As Vatsal suggested, I checked all the sizes of the images and I found that some of them didn't have the same size(Width,Height), so I resized them for having the same size(400,800).

With regard to what Tim said, the images do have that file size, I attach a picture of what I did according to your suggestion of making their file size a multiple of 4.

[Checking the size of the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsl0p.png)

[This is the kind of pictures I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DjXk.png)

However, the video generated from the script still has a size of 6kB.

Comment: Since I don't know how to edit my question, I will post an update here. I found an issue in the size of the pictures, which has already been corrected.  Now framesize = (795,3173), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the size of both images are same? `image_Taylor` and `image_Taylor_5`

Comment: 252kB got a 795x3173 image??  That is hard to believe.  BTW, many video codecs insist that width and height be a multiple of 4.  Why don't you use os.scandir to get the names instead of building them?

Comment: You were right, Vatsal, the images weren't the same size. I've already corrected that issue.

Comment: Yes, Tim. I already checked out the file size and resized them into a multiple of 4. Also, I'm looking forward to optimize the script, adding the suggestion of using os.scandir, as soon as I make it works

Comment: Make sur you arrays are `uint8` with the following shape `(h, w, 3)`. Also, the frame size should be `(w, h)` and not `(h, w)`.